# Python: what does for r in ranger (self.rows) mean? In detail please.

Tags: python-3.x

`for r in range (self.rows):
    color = self.color if color == delf.color2
    else self.color2`

Here is the code where the line is in. Please can you explain the code for me in detail.

Comment: As presented, this is not valid Python code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the code should read:

```
for r in range(self.rows):
    if color == self.color2:
        color = self.color
    else:
        color = self.color2
```

And that this code is located within a Class https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html where the Class defined contains a global variable 'rows'.

Then `for r in range(self.rows)` means: iterate (over the code after the ':') the number of times equal to the number that the variable rows refers to where r will first take the value 0 and end with the value rows - 1.

Hope this helps!